# Loading a nib from a path

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I've been loading nibs programmatically in my app using `[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:`. All I want to do is just contain all my nibs in a subfolder (and their referenced images), but it seems near impossible to load these. loadNibNamed doesn't allow a path to be specified. I've done a ton of searching and can't find any suitable way. Everything else I've tried gives an exception.
I've tried loading the data from file and unarchiving it, but it says it's an incomprehensible archive.
`UINib` has the same problem as `NSBundle`.

There has to be a way to specify the file path, just like loading any other file.

I want the final contents to be an `NSArray` just like `loadNibNamed:` returned.

Any insight would be helpful.

The closest I got was using `[NSBundle bundleWithPath:]` and specifiying the fullpath. It says the path is not yet loaded, and throws and exception. Why is it not loaded?

Comment: Is this subfolder still inside your App Bundle?

Comment: The folder is in the bundle root. It's also under Copy Bundle Resources. All the other folders in the same root load fine. When I look inside the .app the new folder and all it's contents are there. The nib files are the same. I literally just made a new folder, moved the nibs, and relinked the resources with Xcode. When I realized loadNibNamed: didn't work with a path, I started searching and trying all kinds of solutions. But none so far have worked.

Comment: the folder is called nibs one level down from the main bundle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting "not yet loaded" because you are not loading the bundle [bundle load]. Also check for Name case-sensitivity because simulator is generally case-insensitive and Device is not. Try this and see how you go.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: @user1137704, please accept the answer if this has helped solve the problem. Regards,

Comment: I believe this is the correct way of doing it. However, my nibs are simply in a directory, not a bundle. When I call [bundle load] it returns false, and I still get "not yet loaded." Is it possible to treat a directory as an NSBundle in this case? Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @user1137704, if your nib is in the same project or bundle, then you don't need to specify any path. You just need to call Nib with its name. Project subdirectories are only for visual representation but they all are exposed to the same executable path.

Comment: Not just a project subdirectory (folder group); I created a folder outside of Xcode, and added it in Xcode as a folder reference (etc, etc). So the nibs were no longer in the main bundle root directory. I like to keep my resources explicitly organized so when I work with them in other apps, it's not huge mess. I wanted to do the same with nibs.

Comment: At this point, I don't believe this is possible the way I'm trying to achieve it, as the funcionality of nibs and bundles seem to be hardcoded to just work from their root. You can't have a nib in YourApp.app/some_folder/NibName.xib, and load it from the app bundle. It has to be directly under YourApp.app/ or an actual sub-bundle, not just a directory.

Comment: I see what your problem is. I think you can do it. Copy your nib to project bundle and then load it. Copy nib during appropriate load event.

Comment: @user1137704, were you successful in copying and then loading the NIB ?